# To check if internet connection is available or not despite of WIFI turned on?

Tags: android

I am trying to build an app ,where in I first need to check if internet connection is available or not,even if it is connected to the WIFI router which does not have a internet connectivity?From sources I came to know ,in order to check this I need to ping the site for e.g.(www.google.com).Please help me with the exact snippet I need to include? 
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4009133/5552022

Comment: i found a better solution for you check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535092/how-to-check-that-internet-on-local-wifi-is-available-or-not?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check that internet on local wifi is available or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535092/how-to-check-that-internet-on-local-wifi-is-available-or-not)

Comment: @AbhishekJain i  am getting an error on isNetworkAvailable()?

Answer (score 0):

this method work fine for me

```
 public final boolean isInternetOn() {
        // get Connectivity Manager object to check connection
        ConnectivityManager connec =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(getBaseContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Check for network connections
        if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
                connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
                connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            // if connected with internet
            // Toast.makeText(this, " Connected ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;

        } else if (
                connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||
                        connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {

            //  Toast.makeText(this, " Not Connected ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: It still gives "Connected",even if my WIFI has no internet connectivity.Please help?

Comment: check this this question has been already asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535092/how-to-check-that-internet-on-local-wifi-is-available-or-not?rq=1

Comment: if you still encounter problem let me know

Comment: The app force closes!please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public static boolean hasInternet(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```